# Using semantic-ui-less in a Vite React project

Tags: reactjs, less, vite, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I've been trying to install the semantic-ui-less package alongside semantic-ui-react, but upon running with `npm run dev` I get this error:

```
[less] '../../theme.config' wasn't found. Tried - /home/antp/Projects/semantic-test-less/node_modules/semantic-ui-less/theme.config,../theme.config,../../theme.config
5:56:10 PM [vite] Internal server error: [less] '../../theme.config' wasn't found. Tried - /home/antp/Projects/semantic-test-less/node_modules/semantic-ui-less/theme.config,../theme.config,../../theme.config
  Plugin: vite:css
  File: /home/antp/Projects/semantic-test-less/node_modules/semantic-ui-less/definitions/modules/transition.less:19:0
  16 |  @type    : 'module';
  17 |  @element : 'transition';
  18 |  
     |   ^
  19 |  @import (multiple) '../../theme.config';
  20 |  
      at less (file:///home/antp/Projects/semantic-test-less/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:38906:33)
      at async compileCSS (file:///home/antp/Projects/semantic-test-less/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:38277:34)
      at async TransformContext.transform (file:///home/antp/Projects/semantic-test-less/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:37810:56)
      at async Object.transform (file:///home/antp/Projects/semantic-test-less/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:43387:30)
      at async loadAndTransform (file:///home/antp/Projects/semantic-test-less/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:41105:29)
```

**EDIT**: Contents of my `./src/semantic-ui/theme.config`, although just having the package installed and importing `semantic-ui-less/semantic.less` into my React entry file causes the error.

```
/*******************************
        Theme Selection
*******************************/

/* To override a theme for an individual element
   specify theme name below
*/

/* Global */
@site        : 'default';
@reset       : 'default';

/* Elements */
@button      : 'default';
@container   : 'default';
@divider     : 'default';
@flag        : 'default';
@header      : 'default';
@icon        : 'default';
@image       : 'default';
@input       : 'default';
@label       : 'default';
@list        : 'default';
@loader      : 'default';
@placeholder : 'default';
@rail        : 'default';
@reveal      : 'default';
@segment     : 'default';
@step        : 'default';

/* Collections */
@breadcrumb  : 'default';
@form        : 'default';
@grid        : 'default';
@menu        : 'default';
@message     : 'default';
@table       : 'default';

/* Modules */
@accordion   : 'default';
@checkbox    : 'default';
@dimmer      : 'default';
@dropdown    : 'default';
@embed       : 'default';
@modal       : 'default';
@nag         : 'default';
@popup       : 'default';
@progress    : 'default';
@rating      : 'default';
@search      : 'default';
@shape       : 'default';
@sidebar     : 'default';
@sticky      : 'default';
@tab         : 'default';
@transition  : 'default';

/* Views */
@ad          : 'default';
@card        : 'default';
@comment     : 'default';
@feed        : 'default';
@item        : 'default';
@statistic   : 'default';

/*******************************
            Folders
*******************************/

/* Path to theme packages */
@themesFolder : 'themes';

/* Path to site override folder */
@siteFolder  : '../../src/semantic-ui/site';

/*******************************
         Import Theme
*******************************/

@import (multiple) "~semantic-ui-less/theme.less";
@fontPath : '../../../themes/@{theme}/assets/fonts';
/* End Config */
```

I've been looking around but I can't seem to find anything regarding Vite. All possibly related issues were related to create-react-app or webpack.

Answer (score 7):

`semantic-ui-less` relies on the bundler to rewrite the import of `../../theme.config` to your custom `theme.config`. If you check the config of Semantic UI React ( https://react.semantic-ui.com/theming ) the way they do it for CRA is by using CRACO to inject a config into webpack to do this rewriting. This happens inside `@semantic-ui-react/craco-less`: https://github.com/layershifter/semantic-ui-tools/blob/master/packages/craco-less/src/index.js#L16

In vite you can use `resolve.alias` to do this: https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-alias .
For this to work you will have to add `@rollup/plugin-alias` as a devDependency and add something like this to your vite.config.ts:

```
  resolve: {
    // semantic-ui theming requires the import path of theme.config to be rewritten to our local theme.config file
    alias: {
      "../../theme.config": path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        "./src/semantic-ui/theme.config"
      ),
    },
  },
```

When debugging your import paths the debug flag of `vite build` can be of great help: `vite build -d`. It will show you how imports where resolved.

Also if this is a setup for a new project I'd strongly advice against Semantic UI as the maintenance isn't that great and almost died off in the past. As you can see setting up Vite (or anything non-CRA) in the docs as this is missing completely.

EDIT:
Paths will not resolve in the same way they do when using CRA/Webpack. So you'll have to use slightly different values:

Instead of `@import (multiple) "~semantic-ui-less/theme.less";`

use `@import (multiple) "semantic-ui-less/theme.less";`

Instead of `@fontPath : '../../../themes/@{theme}/assets/fonts';`

use `@fontPath : 'semantic-ui-less/themes/@{theme}/assets/fonts';`

Comment: This alias is apparently not sufficient to handle theme overrides. This fixes the of the question though. Did you manage to load your own overrides and variables?

Comment: Oh you're right. I only posted the Vite specific part. The rest pretty much works according to the official docs i.e. you have to have your `theme.config` and a valid `siteFolder` which you point to in your `theme.config`.

And yes, variables and overrides from my `siteFolder` do load correctly. I had to debug and adjust paths via `vite build -d` though.

I'll add my values to the answer.

Comment: Did you do something for this kind of path: `semantic-ui/site/views/card.overrides` ? They're resolved to `null` on my project

Comment: Nothing special really. The according output from vite for me is this: `../../src/semantic-ui/site/views/card.overrides` and it resolves to the correct absolute path in my source.

What is your setting for `@fontPath` in your `theme.config`? Should be something along what the original poster has in theirs:

`@siteFolder : '../../src/semantic-ui/site'`

This folder has to exist in your src of course and should contain all the theme files as stated in the docs: https://react.semantic-ui.com/theming/#scaffold-custom-styles .
See Scaffold Custom Styles

Comment: I couldn't find the correct path for `@siteFolder` (I'm in a monorepo, I can't figure out where he is trying to resolve from). Though, adding `'semantic-ui/site': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/semantic-ui/site')` in vite's resolve alias made the trick. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Up there I meant `@siteFolder` instead of `@fontPath` but editing doesn't work anymore 
Anyway. If you want to add overrides or variables, you'll have to add it to your site folder which should have the same folders and files as the `_site` folder in the semantic-ui package. Again see the Scaffold custom styles part in docs.

The path is resolved starting from the `semantic-ui/semantic.less` file you include in your index.tsx/index.js/whatever.

Comment: Thank you! I'm currently busy with some stuff, but I'll try this when I have some time and come back with feedback.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create `theme.config` file in your project root directory and configure it to your needs Make sure it include the line `@import "../semantic-ui-less/theme.less";` then try run dev again.

```less
@import "../semantic-ui-less/theme.less";
```

Comment: I created the file in my root folder with the same contents as `./src/semantic-ui/theme.config`except for the `@import (multiple) "~semantic-ui-less/theme.less";` line which I replaced with the one you provided, but I'm still getting the same error.